# run a script after one javascript function executed successfully

Tags: javascript

I have 2 functions in javascript. The 2nd one uses result of 1st one.Now I have to use both function in one script. Using simple code (calling both functions) not working as 1st one takes more time..
 any simple solution. Don't want to change code very much??

Comment: Please post relevant code and what you've actually tried.

Comment: Show us some code so we have a better idea on what you are trying to do and better ways to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simple solution :

```
var global;
function func1()
{
    //Function1 Code.Process global
    func2();
}
function func2()
{
       //Function2 code
}
```

Or you could use the callback method as said by Bruno

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `f1` with a callback

```
function f1(callback)
{
    /* code */
    var result = "";

    callback(result);

    return result;
}

function f2(resultFromF1)
{
}
```

And call

```
f1(f2);
```

So when `f1` finishes, `f2` will be executed sending the result of `f1` as a parameter.